# In orchard CMS, make a field required

Tags: orchardcms

I'm editing the content type 'Blog Post' and I've added my own field (type taxonomy). Now I want to make this a required field, so it's mandatory when a user adds a new blog post.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you'll have to create and handle a "Required" property yourself - you should be able to work this out from looking at how it's done for all the inbuilt fields in the Orchard.Fields project. For example, in the Driver for the MediaPickerField:

```
 protected override DriverResult Editor(ContentPart part, Fields.MediaPickerField field, IUpdateModel updater, dynamic shapeHelper) {
            // if the model could not be bound, don't try to validate its properties
            if (updater.TryUpdateModel(field, GetPrefix(field, part), null, null)) {
                var settings = field.PartFieldDefinition.Settings.GetModel<MediaPickerFieldSettings>();

                var extensions = String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(settings.AllowedExtensions)
                        ? new string[0]
                        : settings.AllowedExtensions.Split(new[] {' '}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

                if (extensions.Any() && field.Url != null && !extensions.Any(x => field.Url.EndsWith(x, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))) {
                    updater.AddModelError("Url", T("The field {0} must have one of these extensions: {1}", field.Name.CamelFriendly(), settings.AllowedExtensions));
                }

                if (settings.Required && String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(field.Url)) {
                    updater.AddModelError("Url", T("The field {0} is mandatory", field.Name.CamelFriendly()));
                }
            }

            return Editor(part, field, shapeHelper);
        }
```

Note that just before the editor is returned, it checks if the field has been set to required, and if it has and there's noting provided it calls updater.AddModelError(). I imagine you'll have to implement the Required property for your Taxonomy field, too.

Comment: Hey man, don't just downvote my answer because you're too lazy to implement it. If something is unclear you could have asked for a clarification...